# R:Dividing each element of a list with elements of another list

Tags: r, list, apply

Assume I've one list with three vectors and another list containing three elements:

```
foo_list <- list(vector1=rnorm(10), vector2= rnorm(10), vector3=rnorm(10))
foo_list2 <- list(value1= 2, value2=4, value3=10)
```

Now I want that all 10 numbers of the element of vector1 should be divided by value1 (2), all 10 numbers of the element vector2 should be divided by value2(4) and so on.

This is just a short example. My real lists contains 20 vectors and 20 numbers.
My main calculation is to calculate the percentage changes.

I tried `mapply`, but it gives the wrong results:

```
percentage_change <- function(data, actual) {
  ((data / actual) - 1) * 100
}
foo_results <- mapply(percentage_change, foo_list, foo_list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to use `mapply`:

```
result = mapply(FUN = `/`, foo_list, foo_list2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

---

Though, I get the same results if I fix the syntax in your code:

```
# replaced final `)` with `}`, changed "value" to "actual" in the body
percentage_change <- function(data, actual) {
    ((data / actual) - 1) * 100
}

foo_results <- mapply(percentage_change, foo_list, foo_list2)
result_simple = (mapply(FUN = `/`, foo_list, foo_list2) - 1) * 100
all(foo_results == result_simple)
# [1] TRUE
```

So maybe your code is working and you got the right results? Or maybe it was just the bad function definition?

Answer (score 0):

In a `tidyverse` way you can use `purr::map2` and the following will do what you want

```
library(tidyverse)

results <- purrr::map2(foo_list, foo_list2, ~ .x / .y)
```

Iterating through the elements of `foo_list` and `foo_list2` concurrently